# Every locally connected non separating plane continuum is an AR

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

A continuum is a compact connected metric space. A plane continuum is a continuum contained in $R^2$. We say that a plane continuum does not separate the plane provided that $R^2\setminus X$ is connected.

Theorem. A locally connected plane continuum that does not separate the plane is an AR.

Does anyone knows how to prove this?
Many authors give a reference to Borsuk but the paper is in german.
At least can someone give me a reference to some work in English?
Thanks